# iText 7 SVGConverter does not render as expected

Tags: c#, svg, itext7

I'd like to add an SVG coming from the client on a pdf page. When looking at the SVG on the client as well as the SVG image it looks as expected. However, when the SVG is added to the pdf things like fonts, axis, gridlines, etc. are not drawn as expected.

I have tried playing with the CSS definition for font-familiy and axis definitions but none of them had any effect on the output in the PDF. I'm using some non-standard fonts but even when I tried Arial that did not appear on the PDF.

I‘m using iText 7.1.6

Expected Chart:
[image: Expected Chart]

Resulting SVG in PDF:
[image: Resulting SVG in PDF]

**Code**

```
string fPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(fFolder, fName);

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fPath);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document doc = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);

string svg = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\cData.txt");

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(svg);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{

    Image image = SvgConverter.ConvertToImage(ms, pdf);
    image.SetFixedPosition(0, 400);
    image.ScaleToFit(500, 360);
    doc.Add(image);
}

doc.Close();
```

**SVG Code (copy in txt-Files**

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="reportChartNAVSvg" width="1000" height="720"><defs><style type="text/css">
    .axis--x path { display: none; }
    .axis--y--right path { display: none; }
    .grid line { stroke: #d9d9d9; shape-rendering: crispEdges; }
    .grid path { stroke-width: 0; }
    .line { fill: none; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
    .line-factsheet { color: rgb(198, 180, 147); }
    .bar-factsheet { fill: #faf1d6; stroke: #c6b493; }
    </style></defs><g transform="translate(52 52)"><g class="print" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 26px;"><rect style="fill: #c6b493;" x="114.667" y="617.95" width="52" height="5.2" /><text x="179.6667" y="630.95">Index Performance (CHF)</text></g><g class="grid" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" fill="none" text-anchor="end"><path class="domain" style="opacity: 0;" stroke="currentColor" d="M 948 525.5 H 0.5 V 0.5 H 948" /><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 525.5)"><line style="opacity: 0.7; stroke: #d9d9d9;" stroke="currentColor" x2="948" /><text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" /></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 420.5)"><line style="opacity: 0.7; stroke: #d9d9d9;" stroke="currentColor" x2="948" /><text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" /></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 315.5)"><line style="opacity: 0.7; stroke: #d9d9d9;" stroke="currentColor" x2="948" /><text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" /></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 210.5)"><line style="opacity: 0.7; stroke: #d9d9d9;" stroke="currentColor" x2="948" /><text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" /></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 105.5)"><line style="opacity: 0.7; stroke: #d9d9d9;" stroke="currentColor" x2="948" /><text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" /></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 0.5)"><line style="opacity: 0.7; stroke: #d9d9d9;" stroke="currentColor" x2="948" /><text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" /></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 -104.5)"><line style="opacity: 0.7; stroke: #d9d9d9;" stroke="currentColor" x2="948" /><text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" /></g></g><g class="axis axis-x" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 26px;" fill="none" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0 525)"><path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M 0.5 0.5 H 948.5" /><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(69.4825 0.1)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" /><text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="39">Okt 16</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(171.89 0.1)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" /><text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="39">Jan 17</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(271.98 0.1)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" /><text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="39">Apr 17</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(373.228 0.1)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" /><text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="39">Jul 17</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(475.589 0.1)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" /><text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="39">Okt 17</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(577.997 0.1)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" /><text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="39">Jan 18</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(678.087 0.1)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" /><text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="39">Apr 18</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(779.335 0.1)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" /><text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="39">Jul 18</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(881.696 0.1)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" /><text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="39">Okt 18</text></g></g><g class="axis axis-y-left" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 26px;" fill="none" text-anchor="end"><path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M 0.5 525.5 V 0.5" /><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 525.5)"><line stroke="currentColor" x2="0" /><text style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: end;" fill="currentColor" x="-3" dx="-6.5" dy="0.32em">97</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 420.5)"><line stroke="currentColor" x2="0" /><text style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: end;" fill="currentColor" x="-3" dx="-6.5" dy="0.32em">98</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 315.5)"><line stroke="currentColor" x2="0" /><text style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: end;" fill="currentColor" x="-3" dx="-6.5" dy="0.32em">99</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 210.5)"><line stroke="currentColor" x2="0" /><text style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: end;" fill="currentColor" x="-3" dx="-6.5" dy="0.32em">101</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 105.5)"><line stroke="currentColor" x2="0" /><text style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: end;" fill="currentColor" x="-3" dx="-6.5" dy="0.32em">102</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 0.5)"><line stroke="currentColor" x2="0" /><text style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: end;" fill="currentColor" x="-3" dx="-6.5" dy="0.32em">103</text></g><g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0 -104.5)"><line stroke="currentColor" x2="0" /><text style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: end;" fill="currentColor" x="-3" dx="-6.5" dy="0.32em">104</text></g></g><g><path style="fill: none; stroke: #c6b493; stroke-width: 8;" d="M 0 262.5 L 3.33786 262.5 L 34.4913 290.938 L 67.8699 290.938 L 102.408 371.438 L 135.786 409.5 L 165.827 365.313 L 170.277 368.813 L 204.769 346.5 L 235.922 237.563 L 270.367 225.75 L 300.408 197.313 L 303.746 183.267 L 338.237 154.738 L 371.616 228.914 L 406.107 178.439 L 440.598 163.516 L 473.977 152.104 L 508.514 122.697 L 541.893 148.154 L 571.934 111.724 L 576.384 122.258 L 610.876 96.8008 L 642.029 199.068 L 674.249 217.064 L 676.474 217.064 L 706.515 217.064 L 709.853 157.823 L 744.344 202.917 L 777.723 236.516 L 812.214 224.579 L 846.705 285.588 L 880.084 320.513 L 914.621 425.732 L 948 461.099" /></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: I think it is the UTF8 encoding.  You need to use one of the Window Encoding like 1252.  ASCII the characters 0x00 to 0x7F are the same.  Depending on the country language the characters 0x80 to 0xFF display different.  So you need to use the proper encoding for the language you are using.

Comment: I changed the encoding to Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(svg) but it still looks odd.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1257
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258

Comment: I don't think that this is related to the encoding. If I draw the SVG directly on a page with 

SvgConverter.DrawOnPage(svgString, page);

the result still doesn't look like the expected SVG.

Comment: DrawOnPage still uses an encoding.

Comment: I use german as language. Which encoding'd you propose?

Comment: See following : https://scratchpad.fandom.com/wiki/Character_Encoding_Recommendation_for_Languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to draw the SVG proper on the PDF. With the following code I could resolve the issue regarding the font. Using the propoer Encoding is important if you need to show the chars in the right language.

```
FontProvider provider = new FontProvider();
        provider.AddFont(FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\lte50144.ttf"));

        SvgConverterProperties props = new SvgConverterProperties();
        props.SetCharset("Windows-1252");
        props.SetFontProvider(provider);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(svg);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {

            Image image = SvgConverter.ConvertToImage(ms, pdf, props);
            image.SetFixedPosition(llx, lly);
            image.ScaleToFit(width, height);
            doc.Add(image);
        }
```

The SVG itself is being produced in d3.js. The moved x-axis comes from some `transform` elements on a parent level that is ignored on the child. With a loop over those elemente, removing the `transform`on the parent and set the absolute position on the child resolved this issue.